# Unity LineRenderer making line pink in built version of game

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've seen several articles about this topic on here, but none of the solutions I saw worked for what I was doing. I'm trying to get a line to appear in the game in various colors and it works totally fine in the editor, but once I build it it turns pink, which from what I read means that the material wasn't built in with the rest of the game.

```
line.material.color = Color.yellow;
```

That's the way I'm coloring the lines now. Any suggestions on what to change/add? Thanks in advance!

Comment: When you say 'pink', do you mean magenta? Like when a material or shader is broken?

Comment: You should try and show some more code. I have a feeling this may be with how you assign the material to the line renderer.

Comment: @Immersive Yes my bad, magenta.

Comment: @Immorality that is how I assign it. line is of type LineRenderer, so I'm assigning it directly. Should I add a note that this is the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a separate material and change material color using

> lineMaterial.SetColor("_Color", Color.yellow);

See Screen Shot below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me

```
Color Pink;
ColorUtility.TryParseHtmlString("#CA16B2", out Pink);
LineRender.startColor = Pink;
LineRender.endColor = Pink;
```